# Create a Series using Iterators

Tags: java, iterator

I would like to write a class(called Seii) that is basically a sequence of whole numbers starting from s0. s0 is set in the constructor:

```
se + 1 = 3*(se/2)
```

The catch is: A for-loop should be able to iterate through the objects of this class and spit out the elements of the sequence (without the starting number s0). Also, the sequence ends with the first element larger than 42.

For example:

```
  for(int i:new Seii(2)){

      System.out.println(i)
```

gives out:

`3,4,6,9,10,15,16,24,36,54`

I would like to do it using iterators. Can someone pls help me out?
My idea would be to rewrite the next() method so that it does the calculation for the next element of the sequence, but i'm not getting anywhere with the logic of this.

```
 public class Seii<T> implements Iterator {
   private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
   Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
   private final int size;
   public Seii(int size) {
     this.size = size;
   }

   int seii = 0;

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return false;
   }
   @Override
   public Object next() {
     if ((size % 2) == 0) {
       seii = 3 * (seii/2);
       return seii;
     }
   }

   }
  }
```

This is my implementation.

Comment: Why `Iterator` rather than `Stream`?

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far implementing this?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, because i'm learning how to use Iterators and there is apparently a good implementation of iterators to this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I added my implementation. Its really not that much to work with. I just tried to rewrite the next() method since it returns the actual next element.

Comment: It seems you have bitten off more than you can chew. Start by producing an `Iterator` that produces the [Natural Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Post it on Code Review to see what you can do better. Then move onto, maybe a Fibonacci series. Don't start at the end then ask to be spoon fed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seii` should implement [`Iterable<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which will allow it to support the enhanced for loop syntax. The easiest way of doing that, IMHO, is just to have an inner [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) class which implements your logic:

```
public class Seii implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private class SeiiIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return value <= 42;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            value = 3 * (value / 2);
            return value;
        }
    }


    private int value;

    public Seii(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new SeiiIterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this because the `value` is stored on the `Iterable`, this  ties the state of the `Iterable` to the `Iterator`. This is a violation of the basic contract, and will fail for many use cases - nested loops for example.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to store the sequence, so the array list can be removed from your implementation. All you need is the last value, which can be set in the constructor:

```
// This is a wrapper class that constructs iterators.
// It is used for plugging in your code into enhanced "for" loop
class Seii implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private int current;
    private int max;
    public Seii(int current, int max) {
        this.current = current;
        this.max = max;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new SeiIterator(current, max);
    }
}
// This is the actual iterator that maintains state
// and produces the desired sequence.
class SeiIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private int current;
    private int max;
    public SeiIterator(int current, int max) {
        this.current = current;
        this.max = max;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current < max;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        current = (3*current)/2;
        return current;
    }
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Note that in order to use your iterator in an enhanced `for` loop you need to wrap it in an `Iterable<Integer>`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/NfxWw8)

Comment: Thanks mate, this implementation would also work, but the other implementation above was what i was looking for.

Comment: @TonyOkoth It's the same implementation, really - the differences are cosmetic (e.g. the other implementation hard-codes 42 inside the iterator, and uses a nested class instead of a free-standing one). That's on top of the fact that the other implementation does not work because of parentheses placement (do you see it?)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Seii` class should implement `Iterable<Integer>` not `Iterator`, since that's the interface required by the enhanced for loop. It would have an `iterator` method that returns an instance of a class that implements the `Iterator<Integer>` interface.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i missed that one